# What is the difference between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{ \mathbb{N} \}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the difference between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{ \mathbb{N} \}$?

Note that, here $\mathbb{N}$  is the set of all natural numbers.

Comment: Please put your question in the question body.

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers, $\{\mathbb{N}\}$ is a set containing one element, namely $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused, because of the uppercase N inside curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The same way $\emptyset \neq \{ \emptyset \}$.

One is a set with no elements, the other a set containing a set of no elements.

So in your example, the left is the set of natural numbers, the right a set containing one element, the set of natural numbers.

As I tell my students, it's the difference between an empty box and a box containing an empty box.

Comment: Thanks .  I was confused because of the uppercase letters.

Comment: @RajatDash: The letter is just a name. There's no reason why it should matter whether it is an uppercase letter, lowercase letter, Greek letter, Hebrew letter, or Chinese symbol.